# Unable to trigger Rails form submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I am trying to trigger a rails form submit automatically when the page loads with jQuery. I have followed several Stackoverflow recommendations such as $("form").submit() and $("form").trigger("submit.rails") but with no success. Here is my code:

**Rails index**:

```
<%= form_for [@topic], remote: :true, id: "article-topic" do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, id: "topic-name" %>
    </p>
        <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#topic-name").val("test");
    $("#article-topic").submit();
});
```

**Edit**:
Never mind, I figured it out. Rails automatically assigns their own IDs to forms so the one I was assigning wasn't getting picked up properly. Using :html => { :id => "article-topic" } did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails generates an ID for the form automatically so I had to change the way I was assigning the ID. I updated my form to the below and it now works fine:

```
<%= form_for [@topic], remote: :true, id: "article-topic", :html => { :id => "article-topic" } do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, id: "topic-name" %>
    </p>
        <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a heads-up, Rails just creates [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) on your page, so if you're having trouble binding some events to your DOM, it will likely be a JS issue

As you've already fixed the issue, I'll just detail several points you need to consider:

> 1. Turbolinks
> 2. Submit

--

**Turbolinks**

If you're using Turbolinks in your system, your calling of `$(document).ready` won't hold up for long - you'll be better using one of the [Turbolinks event handlers](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events), like this:

```
var submit_action = function(){
   //do stuff here
}
$(document).on("page:load ready", submit_action);
```

--

**Submit**

Secondly, you'll just be calling the standard `submit` event for your form. I've never seen `submit:rails` before - only `submit` like this:

```
$(#form).on("submit", function(){
   // do something here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I disabled/removed Turbolinks because it had been giving me problems in the past. Yeah, I had never seen submit.rails before either until someone mentioned it in one of the answers I found. I'm using .submit and that works fine anyways.